# font showing on desktop but not on mobile

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, mobile-chrome

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Howard_Fat-Ligh';
    src: url('fonts/Howard_Fat-Ligh/Howard_Fat-Ligh.eot');
    src: url('fonts/Howard_Fat-Ligh/Howard_Fat-Ligh.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/Howard_Fat-Ligh/Howard_Fat-Ligh.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('fonts/Howard_Fat-Ligh/Howard_Fat-Ligh.woff') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/Howard_Fat-Ligh/Howard_Fat-Ligh.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('fonts/Howard_Fat-Ligh.svg#Howard_Fat-Ligh') format('svg');
    font-weight: 100;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

The font renders properly on desktop but does not show on mobile. I checked on Android Firefox and Chrome. Deleted cache on both and tried again. Nothing seems to work. The font files and font-face rule were generated by https://transfonter.org/ and yes the font-face rule is placed at the top of the css file, is not inside any media query that may block the font on smaller screen and is applied at the `body` like this:

```
body{
    font-family: 'Howard_Fat-Light';
}
```

Any clues?

Comment: Any demo, fiddle? Also make sure you do not have font installed locally on desktop system because maybe you are using local font and not external/

Comment: Also, if you are not planning to support zombie browsers like IE8 then there is no point to use any other formats than woff and woff2. https://caniuse.com/#feat=woff